# What are the problems with merging a branch into its grandparent in Git?

Tags: git, merge, branching-and-merging

Let's say I'm working on a refresh of the UI for my app so I have a branch called "v2" to cover all of the code for that project.

Now let's say that I have a branch called "v2-123" representing a particular feature in user story #123, and that my work is more or less complete but is awaiting QA testing approval.

Let's then say that I have another user story #456 which is blocked by user story #456 in that I need the changes in story #123 to be able to work on the changes for #456.

Would it be viable to create branch "v2-456" off of "v2-123" knowing that it's likely QA testing on #123 will complete before I finish working on #456? Would there be problems with then squashing "v2-123" back into "v2", immediately rebasing "v2-456" with "v2" and then later down the line merging "v2-456" back onto "v2"?

Or would it be better to just wait until "v2-123" has been squashed back onto "v2" and branch "v2-456" off of "v2"? The key thing is that I wouldn't want the merging of "v2-123" back onto "v2" to be held up by having to complete "v2-456" first: I want to be able to merge "v2-123" onto "v2" as soon as QA testing comes back successful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Starting a new branch (v2-456) off of v2-123 should not affect the merging of v2-123 back into master at all. It's the v2-456 branch that depends on v2-123 not the other way around:

```
Master -----------------------merge of master and v2-123 ----
         \                   /
          v2-123 ------------
                   \
                    v2-456----
```

The only thing I recommend is that if v2-456 is going to be around for a while (after v2-123 is merged back into master), is merging master back into v2-456 regularly to make the eventual merge of v2-456 back into master less painful.